Stuck with the "KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function" error
As a beginner in this domain, I am stuck with this error and need your help, please.
It's about the implementation of a Variational Autoencoder using TensorFlow/Keras.
I'm encountering an issue when trying to train the model: I get an error related to the KL divergence loss function, specifically with the mu and log_variance variables being treated as symbolic tensors, which leads to the error when used in TensorFlow operations.
I've tried moving the KL loss calculation inside the model, but the issue persists.
x_train is actually a numpy array which should be supported by the fit() method.
def load_dss(spectrograms_path):
  x_train = []
  print(os.getcwd())
  for root, _, file_names in os.walk(spectrograms_path):
    for file_name in file_names:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
        spectrogram = np.load(file_path) # (n_bins, n_frames, 1)
        x_train.append(spectrogram)
  x_train = np.array(x_train)
  if (len(x_train) > 0):
    x_train = x_train[..., np.newaxis] # -> (10006/num_samples, 256, 64, 1)
  return x_train

I actually was able to drill down a bit further: one of the errors comes when evaluating this line:
    def _calculate_combined_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
      reconstruction_loss = self._calculate_reconstruction_loss(y_target, y_predicted)
      kl_loss = self._calculate_kl_loss(self.mu, self.log_variance)
      combined_loss = self.reconstruction_loss_weight * reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
      return combined_loss

the method is supposed to return a Keras Tensor (I think), one parameter is a tf.SymbolicTensor and the last one (kl_loss) is a KerasTensor.
Unfortunately I don't know how to add them, neither to wrap the KerasTensor in a Layer (which I saw is the standard advice for the error)..
I am attaching the 2 source files as well; please note that I am trying to use TF eager execution.
autoencoder.py:
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, ReLU, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Dense, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose, Activation, Lambda
from keras.optimizers import Adam

import keras.random

#tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

class VAE:
    
    def __init__(self,
                 input_shape,
                 conv_filters,
                 conv_kernels,
                 conv_strides,
                 latent_space_dim):
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.conv_filters = conv_filters
        self.conv_kernels = conv_kernels
        self.conv_strides = conv_strides
        self.latent_space_dim = latent_space_dim
        self.reconstruction_loss_weight = 1000000

        self.encoder = None
        self.decoder = None
        self.model = None

        self._num_conv_layers = len(conv_filters)
        self._shape_before_bottleneck = None
        self._model_input = None

        self._build()

    def summary(self):
        self.encoder.summary()
        self.decoder.summary()
        self.model.summary()

    def compile(self, learning_rate=0.0001):
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                           loss=self._calculate_combined_loss,
                           metrics=[self._calculate_reconstruction_loss,
                                    self._calculate_kl_loss])

    def train(self, x_train, batch_size, num_epochs):
        self.model.fit(
                       x_train,
                       x_train,
                       batch_size=batch_size,
                       epochs=num_epochs,
                       shuffle=True)
        print("Done")

    def save(self, save_folder="."):
        self._create_folder_if_it_doesnt_exist(save_folder)
        self._save_parameters(save_folder)
        self._save_weights(save_folder)

    def load_weights(self, weights_path):
        self.model.load_weights(weights_path)

    def reconstruct(self, images):
        latent_representations = self.encoder.predict(images)
        reconstructed_images = self.decoder.predict(latent_representations)
        return reconstructed_images, latent_representations

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, save_folder="."):
        parameters_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "parameters.pkl")
        with open(parameters_path, "rb") as f:
            parameters = pickle.load(f)
        autoencoder = VAE(*parameters)
        weights_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "weights.h5")
        autoencoder.load_weights(weights_path)
        return autoencoder

    def _calculate_combined_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
        reconstruction_loss = self._calculate_reconstruction_loss(y_target, y_predicted)
        kl_loss = self._calculate_kl_loss(self.mu, self.log_variance)
        combined_loss = self.reconstruction_loss_weight * reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        return combined_loss

    def _calculate_reconstruction_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
        error = y_target - y_predicted
        reconstruction_loss = keras.ops.mean(keras.ops.square(error), axis=[1, 2, 3])
        return reconstruction_loss
    
    def _calculate_kl_loss(self, mu, log_variance):
        # KL divergence calculated from the model's mu and log_variance (no longer using them directly here)
        kl_loss = -0.5 * keras.ops.sum(1 + log_variance - keras.ops.square(mu) - keras.ops.exp(log_variance))
        return keras.ops.mean(kl_loss)  # You may also average it if you like

    def _create_folder_if_it_doesnt_exist(self, folder):
        if not os.path.exists(folder):
            os.makedirs(folder)

    def _save_parameters(self, save_folder):
        parameters = [
            self.input_shape,
            self.conv_filters,
            self.conv_kernels,
            self.conv_strides,
            self.latent_space_dim
        ]
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "parameters.pkl")
        with open(save_path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(parameters, f)

    def _save_weights(self, save_folder):
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "weights.h5")
        self.model.save_weights(save_path)

    def _build(self):
        self._build_encoder()
        self._build_decoder()
        self._build_autoencoder()

    def _build_autoencoder(self):
        model_input = self._model_input
        model_output = self.decoder(self.encoder(model_input))
        self.model = keras.Model(model_input, model_output, name="autoencoder")

    def _build_decoder(self):
        decoder_input = self._add_decoder_input()
        dense_layer = self._add_dense_layer(decoder_input)
        reshape_layer = self._add_reshape_layer(dense_layer)
        conv_transpose_layers = self._add_conv_transpose_layers(reshape_layer)
        decoder_output = self._add_decoder_output(conv_transpose_layers)
        self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name="decoder")

    def _add_decoder_input(self):
        return Input(shape=(self.latent_space_dim,), name="decoder_input")

    def _add_dense_layer(self, decoder_input):
        num_neurons = np.prod(self._shape_before_bottleneck)
        dense_layer = Dense(num_neurons, name="decoder_dense")(decoder_input)
        return dense_layer

    def _add_reshape_layer(self, dense_layer):
        return Reshape(self._shape_before_bottleneck)(dense_layer)

    def _add_conv_transpose_layers(self, x):
        for layer_index in reversed(range(1, self._num_conv_layers)):
            x = self._add_conv_transpose_layer(layer_index, x)
        return x

    def _add_conv_transpose_layer(self, layer_index, x):
        layer_num = self._num_conv_layers - layer_index
        conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
            filters=self.conv_filters[layer_index],
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
            strides=self.conv_strides[layer_index],
            padding="same",
            name=f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{layer_num}"
        )
        x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
        x = ReLU(name=f"decoder_relu_{layer_num}")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(name=f"decoder_bn_{layer_num}")(x)
        return x

    def _add_decoder_output(self, x):
        conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
            filters=1,
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[0],
            strides=self.conv_strides[0],
            padding="same",
            name=f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{self._num_conv_layers}"
        )
        x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
        output_layer = Activation("sigmoid", name="sigmoid_layer")(x)
        return output_layer

    def _build_encoder(self):
        encoder_input = self._add_encoder_input()
        conv_layers = self._add_conv_layers(encoder_input)
        bottleneck = self._add_bottleneck(conv_layers)
        self._model_input = encoder_input
        self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, bottleneck, name="encoder")

    def _add_encoder_input(self):
        return Input(shape=self.input_shape, name="encoder_input")

    def _add_conv_layers(self, encoder_input):
        x = encoder_input
        for layer_index in range(self._num_conv_layers):
            x = self._add_conv_layer(layer_index, x)
        return x

    def _add_conv_layer(self, layer_index, x):
        layer_number = layer_index + 1
        conv_layer = Conv2D(
            filters=self.conv_filters[layer_index],
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
            strides=self.conv_strides[layer_index],
            padding="same",
            name=f"encoder_conv_layer_{layer_number}"
        )
        x = conv_layer(x)
        x = ReLU(name=f"encoder_relu_{layer_number}")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(name=f"encoder_bn_{layer_number}")(x)
        return x

    def _add_bottleneck(self, x):
        self._shape_before_bottleneck = (int(x.shape[1]), int(x.shape[2]), int(x.shape[3]))  # Get the shape dimensions
        x = Flatten()(x)
        self.mu = Dense(self.latent_space_dim, name="mu")(x)
        self.log_variance = Dense(self.latent_space_dim, name="log_variance")(x)

        def sample_point_from_normal_distribution(args):
            mu, log_variance = args
            epsilon = keras.random.normal(shape=keras.ops.shape(mu), mean=0., stddev=1.)
            sampled_point = mu + keras.ops.exp(log_variance / 2) * epsilon
            return sampled_point

        x = Lambda(sample_point_from_normal_distribution, output_shape=(self.latent_space_dim,), name="encoder_output")([self.mu, self.log_variance])
        return x



if __name__ == "__main__":
    autoencoder = VAE(
        input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
        conv_filters=(32, 64, 64, 64),
        conv_kernels=(3, 3, 3, 3),
        conv_strides=(2, 2, 2, 2),
        latent_space_dim=2
    )
    autoencoder.summary()

And the train.py:
import os

import numpy as np

from autoencoder import VAE


LEARNING_RATE = 0.0005
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 150

SPECTROGRAMS_PATH = "../../Dataset/Snares/Spectograms"


def load_dss(spectrograms_path):
    x_train = []
    print(os.getcwd())
    for root, _, file_names in os.walk(spectrograms_path):
        for file_name in file_names:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            spectrogram = np.load(file_path) # (n_bins, n_frames, 1)
            x_train.append(spectrogram)
    x_train = np.array(x_train)
    if (len(x_train) > 0):
        x_train = x_train[..., np.newaxis] # -> (10006/num_samples, 256, 64, 1)
    return x_train

def train(x_train, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs):
    autoencoder = VAE(
        input_shape=(256, 64, 1),
        conv_filters=(512, 256, 128, 64, 32),
        conv_kernels=(3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
        conv_strides=(2, 2, 2, 2, (2, 1)),
        latent_space_dim=128
    )
    autoencoder.summary()
    autoencoder.compile(learning_rate)
    autoencoder.train(x_train, batch_size, epochs)
    return autoencoder


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_train = load_dss(SPECTROGRAMS_PATH)
    if (len(x_train) > 0):
        autoencoder = train(x_train, LEARNING_RATE, BATCH_SIZE, EPOCHS)
        autoencoder.save("model")
    else:
        print("No spectrograms found!! " , SPECTROGRAMS_PATH)

If anyone has experience with this problem or could provide some guidance, I would really appreciate your help! I did try to follow some existing answers, they were either too vague or did not work for this code.
Thank you!

Please don't take screenshots of your code and errors. Instead you should include them in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]

Thank you, Markus, I hope I can get some answers..

I fear you won't get any help if you don't comply to the rules of this site. Please share a minimal reproducible example. Don't embed code as screenshots. Don't use external links.

Markus, I am asking for help and the code is publically available in GitHub. If the lack of stack trace is the problem then it might be that Stack Overflow is not anymore the place to get answers but the place to be compliant. I will change the question and let the answers flow, you can guarantee it, right?
